Bring down the y position of the centre item of flutter carousel slider
I'm using carousel_slider flutter plugin. I want to bring down the y-position of the centre item close to half the horizontal axis of the carousel. My code is below :
CarouselSlider.builder(
            itemCount: controller.carousalItems.length,
            carouselController: controller.carouselController,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              viewportFraction: 0.55,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              autoPlay: true,
              autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 7),
              onPageChanged: controller.onPageChanged,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
              return selectedCard(index, controller.carousalItems[index]);
            },
          ),

This is what I am getting :

Where as what I want is this :

I have tried changing multiple parameters of CarouselOptions like enlargeStrategy, enlargeFactor, aspectRatio, etc. but was unable to get the desired result.
Any help, insight to do this is really appreciated.
If there's any flutter carousel library that does this, I would really appreciate mentioning the same. Thanks.
